# Using PKCS 7 Cryptography

Tags: java, cryptography, openssl, keytool, pkcs#7

I need to encrypt and sign data using `PKCS7(CMS)`.
I am using bouncy castle provided api to achieve this using java .
Till now what i understood is i need to follow these steps

1. Need to generate a key pair private & public key using some algorithm say `RSA`
2. Certify it with `X509` certificate
3. Convert it into `PKCS7` key format like p7b
4. Generate java key store using keytool some `*.jks` file
5. Generate the `Certificate Signing Request (CSR)` using keytool command `*.crt`
6. Become self `CA(Certificate Autority)` and certify
7. Import key from keystore created in previous stem and encrypt sign and decrypt data

I still need to figure out what steps i need to follow to sign,encrypt,decrypt data.
*My question is*

1. Is my steps are correct ?
2. How do i certify key pair generated by RSA algorithm and convert into PKCS7 key format
3. How do i become self CA and certify
4. I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026588/pkcs7-encryption) to encrypt and sign, still i am confused with steps to follow and also most of them are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not `BouncyCastle`.

You need `OpenSSL` and a guide.

1. [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/)
2. [How to set up your own certificate authority](http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html)
3. [How to create a self-signed certificate](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)
4. [How to use a certificate in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243018/how-to-load-rsa-private-key-from-file)

Alternatively, to generate and store an RSA key using Java:

[Generate RSA key pair and encode private as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709441/generate-rsa-key-pair-and-encode-private-as-string)